# Google Cloud Function, how to return the status?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

The following function executes successfully, the problem I have is that I need to return the `status` code back, but I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: response.status is not a function

```
  exports.processApplePayment = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  console.log('processApplePayment');

  const stripeToken = data.stripeToken
  const amount = data.amount
  const description = data.description
  const email = data.receipt_email

  console.log('stripeToken', stripeToken);
  console.log('amount', amount);
  console.log('description', description);
  console.log('email', email);


  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: currency,
    description: description,
    source: stripeToken,
    receipt_email: email
    }, function(err, charge) {
      if (err !== null) {

        console.log('error capturing')
        console.log(err)

        response.status(400).send('error')

      } else {

        console.log('success')

        response.status(200).send('success')

      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up [callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTP type functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  Callable functions are declared with `onCall` and accept a single object input, while HTTP functions are declared with `onRequest` and accept a request and response object.  What you've done is declare with `onCall` and expect that you're getting HTTP function arguments.

If you want to write an HTTP type function, declare it like this:

```
exports.processApplePayment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

Comment: I am following the Google docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable (Calling Functions from your app), I am successfully passing it data, my issue is getting the correct ``status` back. - I have updated my question to the latest function code.

Comment: You should continue to follow the instructions on **JUST** that page.  Sending a response involves returning the object to send.  There is no `response.send()` - that's for HTTP type functions. Please be sure you're following the instructions on that page carefully.

Comment: I have followed just that page, and in particular the `return {status: 'success', statusCode: '200'};` doesn't seem to return anything back to the app.

Comment: That's because (now, since you edited), you're not doing JavaScript async programming correctly, which is a whole different issue. Normally, when the advice in an answer causes you to rethink the problem, you should post a new question instead of making drastic edits to the existing question.  You basically just invalidated the answer to the original question, which could have been helpful for others.  :-(

Comment: my apologies, certainly wasn't my intention :( My original intent was to address the issue around returning a value/s on a `onCall` function

Comment: I suggest reverting the change and asking a new question that suits your new problem. The question now even shows the old error message which no longer applies.